# How to select an option from dropdown

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem navigating a website using selenium. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://webtrader.binary.com/v2.2.8/main.html#')

resources = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-1')
resources.click()
```

However, I get the exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-menu-icons"> could not be scrolled into view
```

I don't understand where I went wrong. I am trying to access 'Historical data' from the dropdown menu labeled "Resources". Could someone please help me access it. Maybe I got the id for Resources wrong. You could also check that out.

Comment: i think you need to wait for js to load

Comment: use explicit wait

Comment: You might say the question is similar to other previous ones, but it is not. I have tried more than 5 other solutions in related questions without success.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal have you tried it out?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya could you please write the code for that and test it. I'm sure it's not that many lines needed. Please.

Comment: you have to first open the dropdown and then select the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you want to click to open the dropdown is the previous sibling of the element `resources`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('resources').click()
historical_data = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ui-id-4')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things happening here. First of all, your code is lacking a wait. Without it will always fail, as the page is dynamically loaded. Read about [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Secondly, here `resources = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-1')` you are finding the element from the dropdown menu, and then you are trying to click it. But the dropdown menu is not opened. You should click on it, then wait for the option to appear, only then click on the 'Historical data'.